# How do I get IE to prompt before opening a pdf file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

When clicking on a link to a pdf file, Internet Explorer simply opens it in Adobe Reader. How do I make it ask for confirmation first?

Comment: One way is to uninstall Adobe PDF reader and use a third-party PDF reader, such as Nitro PDF or Sumatra. This is not actually an answer, just a work-around.